# Android: ProgressBar for HttpURLConnection String data

Tags: android, progress-bar, httpurlconnection, stringbuilder, simpledateformat

I am getting JSON data from a web service and would like to display a progress bar while the data is downloading. All the examples I have seen use a StringBuilder like so:

```
//Set up the initial connection
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

connection.connect();

InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

//read the result from the server
reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line + '\n');
}

result = builder.toString();
```

I got the ProgressBar to work by downloading the data as a byte array, then converting the byte array to a String, but I'm wondering if there is a 'more correct' way to do this. Since I've found no other way of doing this, the following class can also serve as a working example, seems a bit of a hack, but it does work well.

```
package com.royaldigit.newsreader.services;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.royaldigit.newsreader.controller.commands.CommandInterface;
import com.royaldigit.newsreader.model.data.SearchResultDO;
import com.royaldigit.newsreader.model.data.SearchTermDO;

/**
 * Gets news results from Feedzilla based on the search term currently stored in model.searchTermDO
 * 
 * Sends progress update and returns results to the CommandInterface command reference:
 * * command.onProgressUpdate(progress);
 * * command.serviceComplete(results);
 *
 *
 */
public class FeedzillaSearchService {
    private static final String TAG = "FeedzillaSearchService";
    private static final String SERVICE_URI = "http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q=";
    private static final int STREAM_DIVISIONS = 10;

    private CommandInterface command;
    private SearchTermDO currentSearchTermDO;
    private Integer maximumResults;
    private DownloadTask task;
    private ArrayList<SearchResultDO> results;
    public Boolean isCanceled = false;

    public void getData(CommandInterface cmd, SearchTermDO termDO, Integer maxResults){
        command = cmd;
        currentSearchTermDO = termDO;
        //Feedzilla only allows count to be 100 or less, anything over throws an error
        maximumResults = (maxResults > 100)? 100 : maxResults;
        results = new ArrayList<SearchResultDO>();
        task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        isCanceled = true;
        if(task != null) task.cancel(true);
    }

    /**
     * Handle GET request
     *
     */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void...voids) {
            String result = "";
            if(currentSearchTermDO == null || currentSearchTermDO.term.equals("")) return result;

            BufferedReader reader = null;

            publishProgress(0);

            try {
                String path = SERVICE_URI + URLEncoder.encode(currentSearchTermDO.term, "UTF-8") + "&count=" + maximumResults;
                Log.d(TAG, "path = "+path);
                URL url = new URL(path);

                //Set up the initial connection
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

                connection.connect();

                int length = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                byte[] data = new byte[length];
                int bufferSize = (int) Math.ceil(length / STREAM_DIVISIONS);
                int progress = 0;
                for(int i = 1; i < STREAM_DIVISIONS; i++){
                    int read = stream.read(data, progress, bufferSize);
                    progress += read;
                    publishProgress(i);
                }
                stream.read(data, progress, length - progress);
                publishProgress(STREAM_DIVISIONS);

                result = new String(data);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception "+e.toString());
            } finally {
                if(reader != null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch(IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            int currentProgress = progress[0] * 100/STREAM_DIVISIONS;
            if(!this.isCancelled()) command.onProgressUpdate(currentProgress);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            if(!this.isCancelled()) downloadTaskComplete(result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param data
     */
    private void downloadTaskComplete(Object data){
        if(!isCanceled){
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString());
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data.toString());

                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    SearchResultDO dataObj = new SearchResultDO();
                    dataObj.title       = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                    dataObj.url         = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
                    dataObj.snippet     = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("summary");
                    dataObj.source      = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("source");
                    dataObj.date        = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("publish_date");
                    dataObj.termId      = currentSearchTermDO.id;

                    //Reformat date
                    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
                    try {
                        Date date = format1.parse(dataObj.date);
                        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        dataObj.date = format2.format(date);
                    } catch(ParseException pe) {
                        Log.e(TAG, pe.getMessage());
                    }

                    results.add(dataObj);
                }
                command.serviceComplete(results);
            } catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                command.serviceComplete(results);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here is the finished version of the class using the suggestions from Nikolay. I ended up using the StringBuilder after all. The previous version would break because some times connection.getContentLength() returns -1. This version degrades gracefully for that case. Tested this implementation quite a bit and it seems bulletproof.

```
package com.royaldigit.newsreader.services;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.royaldigit.newsreader.controller.commands.CommandInterface;
import com.royaldigit.newsreader.model.data.SearchResultDO;
import com.royaldigit.newsreader.model.data.SearchTermDO;

/**
 * Gets news results from Feedzilla based on the search term currently stored in model.searchTermDO
 * 
 * Sends progress update and returns results to the CommandInterface command reference:
 * * command.onProgressUpdate(progress);
 * * command.serviceComplete(results);
 *
 */
public class FeedzillaSearchService implements SearchServiceInterface {
    private static final String TAG = "FeedzillaSearchService";
    private static final String SERVICE_URI = "http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q=";

    private CommandInterface command;
    private SearchTermDO currentSearchTermDO;
    private Integer maximumResults;
    private DownloadTask task;
    private ArrayList<SearchResultDO> results;
    private Boolean isCanceled = false;

    public void getData(CommandInterface cmd, SearchTermDO termDO, Integer maxResults){
        command = cmd;
        currentSearchTermDO = termDO;
        //Feedzilla only allows count to be 100 or less, anything over throws an error
        maximumResults = (maxResults > 100)? 100 : maxResults;
        results = new ArrayList<SearchResultDO>();
        task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        isCanceled = true;
        if(task != null) task.cancel(true);
    }

    /**
     * Handle GET request
     *
     */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void...voids) {
            String result = "";
            if(currentSearchTermDO == null || currentSearchTermDO.term.equals("")) return result;

            BufferedReader reader = null;

            publishProgress(0);

            try {
                String path = SERVICE_URI + URLEncoder.encode(currentSearchTermDO.term, "UTF-8") + "&count=" + maximumResults;
                Log.d(TAG, "path = "+path);
                URL url = new URL(path);

                //Set up the initial connection
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
                connection.connect();

                //connection.getContentType() should return something like "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                String[] values = connection.getContentType().toString().split(";");
                String charset = "";
                for (String value : values) {
                    value = value.trim();
                    if (value.toLowerCase().startsWith("charset=")) {
                        charset = value.substring("charset=".length());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //Set default value if charset not set
                if(charset.equals("")) charset = "utf-8";

                int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                /**
                 * connection.getContentLength() can return -1 on some connections.
                 * If we have the content length calculate progress, else just set progress to 100 and build the string all at once.
                 * 
                 */
                if(contentLength>-1){
                    //Odd byte array sizes don't always work, tried 512, 1024, 2048; 1024 is the magic number because it seems to work best.
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    int totalRead = 0;
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(data)) > 0) {
                        try {
                            builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, charset));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid charset: " + e.getMessage());
                            //Append without charset (uses system's default charset)
                            builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
                        }
                        totalRead += bytesRead;
                        int progress = (int) (totalRead * (100/(double) contentLength));
                        //Log.d(TAG, "length = " + contentLength + " bytesRead = " + bytesRead + " totalRead = " + totalRead + " progress = " + progress);
                        publishProgress(progress);
                    }
                } else {
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line + '\n');
                        publishProgress(100);
                    }
                }
                result = builder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception "+e.toString());
            } finally {
                if(reader != null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch(IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            if(!this.isCancelled()) command.onProgressUpdate(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            if(!this.isCancelled()) downloadTaskComplete(result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param data
     */
    private void downloadTaskComplete(Object data){
        if(!isCanceled){
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString());
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data.toString());

                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    SearchResultDO dataObj = new SearchResultDO();
                    dataObj.title       = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                    dataObj.url         = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
                    dataObj.snippet     = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("summary");
                    dataObj.source      = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("source");
                    dataObj.date        = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("publish_date");
                    dataObj.termId      = currentSearchTermDO.id;

                    //Reformat date
                    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
                    try {
                        Date date = format1.parse(dataObj.date);
                        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat(SearchResultDO.DATE_FORMAT_STRING);
                        dataObj.date = format2.format(date);
                    } catch(ParseException pe) {
                        Log.e(TAG, pe.getMessage());
                    }

                    results.add(dataObj);
                }
            } catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
            command.serviceComplete(results);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great! Last UPDATE is working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since content length is reported in bytes, there is really no other way. If you want to use a `StringReader` you could take the length of each line you read and calculate the total *bytes* read to achieve the same thing. Also, the regular idiom is to check the return value of `read()` to check if you have reached the end of the stream. If, for some reason, the content length is wrong, your code may read more/less data then available. Finally, when converting a byte blob to a string, you should explicitly specify the encoding. When dealing with HTTP, you can get that from the 'charset' parameter of the 'Content-Type' header.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful info. I will post an update when your suggestions have been implemented.

Comment: I found that you can use a StringBuilder in this case like so: builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, charset));
I implemented all your suggestions, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I tried the solution of Jeremy C, but it was inaccurate, because value of "Content-Length" from header can be very different than real data.

My solution is:

1. Send HTTP header from server (PHP):

   ```
   $string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
   header("X-Size: ".strlen($string)); //for example with name: "X-Size"
   print($string);
   ```
2. Read correct value "X-size" for contentLength variable from HTTP header before read from stream:

   ```
   protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
       if (General.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "WebAsyncTask(doInBackground)");

       String result = "";
       BufferedReader reader = null;

       try {
           HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
           conn.setConnectTimeout(General.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
           conn.setReadTimeout(General.TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
           conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
           conn.connect();

           if (General.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "X-Size: "+conn.getHeaderField("X-Size"));    
           if (General.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "getHeaderField: "+conn.getHeaderFields());   

           if(conn.getResponseCode() != General.HTTP_STATUS_200)
               return General.ERR_HTTP;

           int contentLength = -1;
           try {
               contentLength = Integer.parseInt(conn.getHeaderField("X-Size"));
           } catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
           reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

           //Pokud delku zname:
           if(contentLength > -1){
               byte[] data = new byte[16]; //TODO
               int totalRead = 0;
               int bytesRead = 0;

               while ((bytesRead = stream.read(data)) > 0){

                   Thread.sleep(100);  //DEBUG TODO

                   try {
                       builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8"));
                   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                       Log.i(TAG, "Invalid charset: " + e.getMessage());
                       //Append without charset (uses system's default charset)
                       builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
                   }

                   totalRead += bytesRead;
                   int progress = (int) (totalRead * (100/(double) contentLength));
                   Log.i(TAG, "length = " + contentLength + " bytesRead = " + bytesRead + " totalRead = " + totalRead + " progress = " + progress);
                   publishProgress(progress);
               }
           } else { 
               String line = "";
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   builder.append(line + '\n');
                   publishProgress(100);
               }
           }

           result = builder.toString();
       } catch (SocketException | SocketTimeoutException e){
           if (General.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "SocketException or SocketTimeoutException");
           e.printStackTrace();
           return General.HTTP_TIMEOUT;
       } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           return General.ERR_HTTP;
       } finally {
           if (reader != null) {
               try {
                 reader.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```